# Imitating a click on a dynamically added element with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a ReactJS-based website which I wanna navigate programmatically. Basically, the workflow is looped:

1. Click on Element1.
2. The web page code is dynamically altered, during which Element2 is added.
3. Click on Element2.

Etc, until, after clicking on ElementN, the web page returns to the initial state and Element1 is displayed again. Clicking on those elements is what I wanna automate from within the website itself.

I have an access to the JS file that is responsible for the website contents creation and alteration. I can locate the code which describes the elements I'm interested in, and add any extra event listeners if need be.

I'm almost completely new to the client-side development, so my approach to solving this task is purely intuitive. So far my idea was to add an event listener for some sort of "onAdded" event which would fire when the element is added to DOM, and from that listener call the "onclick" listener (or dispatch the "click" event in some other way). However, i can't find any events that would indicate an addition to the DOM tree.

So, strictly speaking, i have two questions:

1. Is the approach described above viable (and adequate)? If so, then how exactly do i accomplish it?
2. If i'm doing it all wrong then what would be the right way to accomplish my task?

## Edit 1

As per Matthew Herbst's suggestion, I looked into React lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount`. Turns out, the elements I wanna automate clicking on are not independent React component but some other component's contents added inside the `render` method with a huge chain of `createElement` calls.

So now the problem switches from detecting a moment when a particular element is added to the DOM structure to finding a way to interact with it.

The easy (and ugly) way to do it, as I currently see it, is to use the `window` object from `componentDidMount`, locate the element I wanna click by its `data-reactid` attribute (which is a string of dot-separated digits which, from what I can tell, is generated dynamically and reflects the element hierarchy) and then dispatch the required DOM event.

It might work, but if the document structure changes then the values of the `data-reactid` then it's all broken again. I would prefer to somehow dispatch the React's own `onClick` event properly, but I don't know how. I tried calling the function that gets passed to the `createElement` method as a value of the `onClick` property from `componentDidMount`, but for some reason it doesn't work.

I have also tried the method of interacting with DOM described in [this article](http://jamesknelson.com/react-js-by-example-interacting-with-the-dom/), but in my case the `ReactDOM` object doesn't seem to be defined.

Since I'm not much of a client-side developer, especially not a React guru, I don't really see the whole picture of how the website's client logic is working, and the code I'm working with seems to be minified/obfuscated to make it even harder. So if anyone could provide any specific suggestions without sending me to read all the React documentation, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Since your app is React, you should be very interested in the [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) and [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate) lifecycle methods.

Comment: All of that can be managed by state. click on element1 setState, data changes because state changes which renders element2 click on that setState and the cycle continues

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, thank you for your suggestions. Following down that path led me to reformulating my initial question. Please look into the post's edits for details.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I don't think there is a good/pretty solution to what you want. The best way that I've thought of is to have a common way of settings refs in every component. Then, build a [mixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins) that you can add to every component. The methods in the mixin would then be called by each component's various lifecycle methods. Since your refs would all match some predefined format, the mixin can look for the refs in the component.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not sure if a question as profane as mine should be answered at all, but it looks like I got it figured out.

The minified/obfuscated code I had to deal with still had prominent features of a React application, such as objects with series of callbacks like `render`, `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`. So, just like Matthew Herbst suggested, I looked into the things they do.

The elements clicking on which I needed to automate were created inside the `render` methods by long chains of `createElement` calls which looked something like this:

```
T["default"].createElement("li", null, T["default"].createElement("div", {
    className: P["default"].img
}, T["default"].createElement("img", {
    src: n(600),
    alt: ""
}), T["default"].createElement("b", null , "+3")), T["default"].createElement("h4", null , "«Header text»", T["default"].createElement("b", null , "+3")), T["default"].createElement("p", null , "Description"), T["default"].createElement("div", {
    className: P["default"].btn
}, T["default"].createElement(A.Btn, {
    mod: "info",
    onClick: this._router.bind(this, "/gtr", "gtr")
}, "Play")))
```

I should have posted that code in the original post, but back then I didn't really understand what's going on here.

It turns out, the object referred to by `T["default"]` is a `React` object, meaning that `T["default"].createElement` calls were actually equivalent to the `React.createElement` ones.

Then, the [article by James K. Nelson](http://jamesknelson.com/react-js-by-example-interacting-with-the-dom/) helped, which explained that in order to locate a specific child of a component I need to assign a `ref` attribute to it. I needed to access that "Play" button, so I tried adding a `ref` property to what looked like its descriptor object, so it would look like

```
T["default"].createElement(A.Btn, {
    mod: "info",
    ref: "automatedElement1",
    onClick: this._router.bind(this, "/gtr", "gtr")
}, "Play")
```

, and it worked. Now, inside the `componentDidUpdate` method I could use the code like

```
if (this.refs.hasOwnProperty("automatedElement1")) {
    var buttonElement = this.refs.automatedElement1;
}
```

Unfortunately, I didn't quite understand how to get from this object to its DOM reflection, but by simply studying its contents I managed to find a property which corresponds to the value of the `data-reactid` attribute of an HTML element of that button. So then I found no smarter solution than to acquire the element's DOM node by using the `document.querySelector` method:

```
var buttonNode = document.querySelector('button[data-reactid="' + buttonElement._reactInternalInstance._rootNodeID + '"]');

if (buttonNode) {
    buttonNode.click();
}
```

This might be a bad solution, but that's the solution I managed to find in my situation, and it works. Hope it helps anyone who had a rough encounter with a React application and didn't know where to start.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. You should know that the [newest version of React, v15.0](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html), removed the use of the `data-reactid` attribute.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, what would be the idiomatic way of achieving the same result but without relying on using of `data-reactid` then?